# Infidelity in Java writing Unicode characters to xls file

Tags: java, browser, unicode, file-format

I have a JSP page with a function that exports a table of data into a document that is interpreted as a Microsoft Excel document. I use this code to set the content disposition header:

```
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
        "attachment; filename=\"" + course.getName()
            + "_Enrollment.xls\"");
```

Then I write the table of data to the page. When the writing is complete, my browser (Safari) automatically treats the file as an attachment and downloads it. I can open the file with Excel or TextEdit. The problem is, when I write a non-ASCII Unicode character such as a-grave (à) to the document, it appears in the resulting text document as double dagger (‡). What can I do to change this behavior?

Comment: How are you creating an XLS file? With a library like Apache POI, or are you just generating CSV data that Excel can open? Also, you say you write a Unicode character, but how do you write it? As UTF-8? UTF-16?

Comment: Just generating a tab-delimited text file that Excel can open. To write the data, I just use <%= varName %> where varName is a Java String variable whose value may contain Unicode characters. Sorry, I'm a newbie, I may not be explaining it well.